# Playing sound with alertdialog box

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i m making a quiz app , in my quizzActivity where qestions load  i used countDowntimer  so when this countdown timer is finished i m displaying alert dialog of Game over  with sound , everything working fine

Problem is when my quiz is finished , i am also getting the Gameover sound in my result activity , and in MainActivity.

my QuizzActvity code

```
ActivityQuizBinding binding;

ArrayList<Questions> qestions;

Questions question;

CountDownTimer timer;

FirebaseFirestore database;

int correctAnswer = 0;

MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

int index = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    binding = ActivityQuizBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    qestions = new ArrayList<>();
    database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    final String cateGoryID = getIntent().getStringExtra("categoryID");


    database.collection("categories")
            .document(cateGoryID)
            .collection("questions")
            .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                Questions questions = snapshot.toObject(Questions.class);
                qestions.add(questions);
            }
            Collections.shuffle(qestions);
            setNextQestions();
        }
    });


    resetTimer();

}

void resetTimer() {

    timer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {

            binding.timer.setText(String.valueOf(l / 1000));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(QuizActivity.this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.sad)
                    .setTitle("Oops Game Over!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setMessage(" Please Try Again ")
                    .setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                            Intent in = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(in);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }).create().show();

            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(QuizActivity.this, R.raw.wrong);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mMediaPlayer.start();



        }
    };
}

public void CheckAnwer(TextView textView) {
    String selectAnswer = textView.getText().toString();
    if (selectAnswer.equals(question.getAnswer())) {
        correctAnswer++;
        textView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.option_right));
    } else {
        showAnswer();
        textView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.option_wrong));
    }
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(QuizActivity.this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_person_24)
            .setMessage("Are you sure want to Quit Game")
            .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Intent in = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    }).create().show();

}


public void setNextQestions() {

    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
    }

    timer.start();

    if (index < qestions.size()) {
        binding.qestioncounter.setText(String.format("%d/%d", (index + 1), qestions.size()));
        question = qestions.get(index);
        binding.qestions.setText(question.getQestion());
        binding.option1.setText(question.getOption1());
        binding.option2.setText(question.getOption2());
        binding.option3.setText(question.getOption3());
        binding.option4.setText(question.getOption4());
        index++;
    } else {
        reset();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Quiz Finsished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent in = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("correct_answer", correctAnswer);
        in.putExtra("total", qestions.size());
        startActivity(in);

    }
}

void reset() {
    binding.option1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.option_unselected));
    binding.option2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.option_unselected));
    binding.option3.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.option_unselected));
    binding.option4.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.option_unselected));
}


void showAnswer() {
    if (question.getAnswer().equals(binding.option1.getText().toString()))
        binding.option1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.option_right));

    else if (question.getAnswer().equals(binding.option2.getText().toString()))
        binding.option2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.option_right));

    else if (question.getAnswer().equals(binding.option3.getText().toString()))
        binding.option3.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.option_right));

    else if (question.getAnswer().equals(binding.option4.getText().toString()))
        binding.option4.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.option_right));

}

public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.option_1:
        case R.id.option_2:
        case R.id.option_3:
        case R.id.option_4:
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
            TextView selected = (TextView) view;
            CheckAnwer(selected);
            break;

        case R.id.next_btn:
            reset();
            setNextQestions();
            break;


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Adding timer.cancel inside reset() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have to stop the ***MediaPlayer*** before switching to another activity. You may use the `OnActivityResult` result for stopping Mediaplayer while switching between activities.
- Here is the sample code:

```
  public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

```
  Intent in = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
  startActivityForResult(in, REQUEST_CODE);
```

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE  && resultCode  == RESULT_OK) {

               mMediaPlayer.stop()
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            
        }

    }
```

- Also, make sure that you cancel the CountDownTimer before switching to another activity.

Comment: Working Fine  ..But  can i use Thread.sleep() for 1 sec delay then stopping the media player

Comment: I haven't used threads much, but as far as I know, `Thread.sleep()` freezes the process from UI. Since it is a Mediaplayer, I didn't think it will help you, but I recommend you to experiment and let me know.

Comment: it worked but problem is there is little time lag between the dialog and  sound

Comment: Hey thanks for sharing, I'm looking forward to learn more about this. Also, sorry for replaying late.